# Button calc stopped working

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a simple program that does a calculation on a button press. The result is placed into a label using the following code:

```
//converts the float to 2 descimal places then converts it to a string
NSString *stringRectResult=[[NSString alloc]
                            initWithFormat:@"%1.2f",floatCalcResult];

//displays the string result in the label
resultLabel.text=stringRectResult;
```

It works perfectly, however, I added in code to hide the decimal keyboard when the user touches off the keyboard. That works, but when I added this code the button to update the label no longer worked. Can anyone help? The code to hide the keyboard is below. The app works when I comment it out but does not when it is active

In `viewDidLoad`:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]
initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tap:)];
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:tapRecognizer];
```

Tap selector...

```
-(void)tap:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gr
{
    [self.view endEditing:YES];
}
```

Thanks for any and all help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that by intercepting all of the user's taps (in order to hide the keyboard), you're preventing any other user interface elements from being tapped. I would urge you to rethink your design; it's not usually necessary to have an explicit facility to hide the keyboard.

If you do want to keep this design, you can implement the `gestureRecognizer:shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:` method in your class:

```
- (void) viewDidLoad
{
    // ...

    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]
        initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tap:)];
    tapRecognizer.delegate = self;
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:tapRecognizer];
}

- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer
{
    return YES;
}
```

Two things to keep in mind:

1. You need to mark your view controller as conforming to the `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate` protocol.
2. If you later add a second gesture recognizer to the view, you'll need to add a check inside the second method to treat the second recognizer differently.

Comment: thanks for that. honestly the design im not set with, that was the only way i knew/found out about hiding the decimal keyboard since it doesnt have a return key

Comment: program jumps to debug on tap using this.

Comment: stops in main.m on   int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([TipAppDelegate class]));
    }
}

Comment: That information isn't enough to tell what went wrong. What does the debug log say?